# Image upload broken since server change to php 5.6

Tags: php, image, file-upload, upload

This code was working well until my server upgrade to PHP 5.6.

```
<?php

if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"])) {
    $imageData = $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];

    $filteredData = substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);
    $unencodedData = base64_decode($filteredData);

    $fn = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] : false);
    $fp = fopen('upload/' . $fn, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $unencodedData);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

I'm a noob at PHP, tweaking open-source code when I need it.

Comment: this is old code using `GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]` replace it

Comment: Would be smart to take a look at the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php (deprecated since 5.6). I would take a look at the PHP-error log, to see if there is anything there. Not entirely sure why you use something like what you're using here to begin with, but if you're just picking examples and messing about, that explains it, I guess...

Comment: 'this is old code using GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] replace it'. Erm.. thanks. Useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep "HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA" was the culprit. As well as setRequestHeader no longer accepting underscores.
In answer to your question junkfoodjunkie it's for this http://www.screentoys.com
I built it as a learning project a few years ago but the 'load your own photo and save it' feature had stopped working, hence my post. I hadn't touched it for a fair while and so only noticed recently.
After some experimentation here's the fix:

```
$img = file_get_contents("php://input");
$img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$fn = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] : false);
file_put_contents('upload/'.$fn, $data);
```

Had to change:
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME", dropOneName);
to:
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-FILENAME", dropOneName);
in the JS as well.

It saves a drag 'n dropped canvas image to the server.